# Regex to replace an xml content java

Tags: java, regex

I need to replace xml content with empty string.

```
  <credential location="PropertyFileInventoryProvider" name="CLI_SESSION_PARENT_SCRIPT">&lt;cliSession xmlns="http://example.com/cfr2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" formatVersion="1" xsi:schemaLocation="http://example.com/cfr2 xdeCliSessionScript.xsd"&gt;
    &lt;/cliSession&gt;</credential>
```

I build the following regex but its not working.

```
val.replaceAll("<credential location=\"PropertyFileInventoryProvider\" name=\"CLI_SESSION_PARENT_SCRIPT\">[\\s\\S]*?</credential>", "");
```

Comment: maybe `val = val.replaceAll("<credential ....");`

Comment: Did you remember to assign the result of your `replaceAll` call? Remember that it *returns* a modified string but does not modify the input string itself.

Comment: i have multiple credential tags in that i need to remove only the which has content as CLI_SESSION_PARENT_SCRIPT.

Comment: What do you need to replace from that xml?

Comment: Need to replace the xml tag with empty string .eg : ""

Comment: XML is not text "for real". Parse-modify-rewrite is the correct way to alter parts of it. String-based magics will die if new attributes appear, or just the existing ones get reordered.

Answer (score 2):

- Using regular expressions to process XML is a *bad idea*. It's not forward-compatible. Your program just waits to fail in future. There are too many options how to write XML in a semantically identical way which are too difficult to capture by a regular expression. For example, the attribute values could be enclosed with apostrophes instead of quotes. The sequence of the attributes could differ. The amount and type of whitespace before or after the attributes could differ. There could even be whitespace before or after the equals sign of attribute values. Namespace declarations could be introduced. Attributes of XML or other namespaces could be introduced. Comments could be inserted. When the program that produces above XML file is changed slightly, and the sequence of the attributes is changed, the resulting XML is semantically identical, but your regular expression breaks.
- Your regular expression could be simplified to `[^<]` instead of `[\\s\\S]` because `[\\s\\S]` actually is `.` but you might want to exclude `<`.
- You do not assign the value. Remember, in Java `String` is immutable. In order to get the replaced string, you need to assign the return value. So, probably `val = val.replaceAll(...)`.

Thus your Java code should probably be:

```
val = val.replaceAll("<credential location=\"PropertyFileInventoryProvider\" name=\"CLI_SESSION_PARENT_SCRIPT\">[^<]*?</credential>", "");
```

You could achieve similar results with XSLT and XPath or DOM and XPath, in a much more robust way. For example, you could remove all nodes that match `credential[@location="PropertyFileInventoryProvider"][@name="CLI_SESSION_PARENT_SCRIPT"]`

The following XSLT would do that:

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template
        match='
            credential
                [@location="PropertyFileInventoryProvider"] 
                [@name="CLI_SESSION_PARENT_SCRIPT"]
        '
    />
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
<xsl:transform>
```

Comment: I tried like val = val.replaceAll("<credential [a-zA-Z\\=\"+A-Za-z\\s+a-z\\=\"CLI_SESSION_PARENT_SCRIPT\">][^<]*?</credential>","");  but no luck

Comment: Now that RE that you just gave definitely cannot work. Please read the documentation of Pattern. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: Even this did not work. val = val.replaceAll("<credential location=\"PropertyFileInventoryProvider\" name=\"CLI_SESSION_PARENT_SCRIPT\">[^<]*?</credential>", "");

Answer (score 0):

For your Credentials tag this should work :

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

class Demo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String temp = "<credential location=\"PropertyFileInventoryProvider\" name=\"CLI_SESSION_PARENT_SCRIPT\">&lt;cliSession xmlns=\"http://example.com/cfr2\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" formatVersion=\"1\" xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://example.com/cfr2 xdeCliSessionScript.xsd\"&gt;\r\n" + 
                "    &lt;/cliSession&gt;</credential>";
        String newString = StringUtils.substringBetween(temp, "credential");
        String emptyCredTag = temp.replaceAll(newString, "");
        temp = emptyCredTag.replaceAll(emptyCredTag, "");
        System.out.println(temp);
    }   
}
```

Add this dependency to your project :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

It will help you out upto an extent but for all Credential tags you have to find a logic that will be implemented using this StringUtils class i.e you have to find a way as how to iterate through all tags and then using StringUtils.substringBetween() method.

For your this XML snippet it will work definitely .
Hope that helps you.

Comment: val = val.replaceAll("<credential[^>]+CLI_SESSION_PARENT_SCRIPT[^>]+>[^<]+</credential>",
      "<credential name =\"CLI_SESSION_PARENT_SCRIPT\">cliSession</credential>");